# hdfs log file is too huge

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

after a lot of read and write operation to the hdfs , (i don't know the exact operation that cause this problem).
these two files :
**dncp_block_verification.log.curr   , 
dncp_block_verification.log.prev**
are more than 200 000 000 000 byte each.

what operation to hdfs may cause these file grow **fast**?

from the internet I know that I could shotdown the hdfs and delete the log,but it is not the good solution.
how to avoid this problem? thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block scanner is what is causing the files to grow.  Here's a link to an article explaining the behavior:  http://aosabook.org/en/hdfs.html (Section 8.3.5).

The [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6114) which causes this has been fixed in HDFS 2.6.0

Comment: Looks like this may be a bug in the block scanner:  HDFS-6114 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6114

Comment: So we should wait for the release

Comment: Thanks to @martin-serrano for the edit to show that the bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar situation with my 20 datanode cluster.  I've seen several reports of this reportedly being a bug.  I'm seeing this behavior with CDH 5.0.2 which runs HDFS 2.3.x.

I had 1 node out of 20 use 100% of all available space because of the two dncp_block_verification logs.  The other nodes seem to have very typical log sizes and I can't figure out why this one node had an issue.

I manually deleted the two files and that resolved my issue with no adverse behavior.  Unfortunately, I don't know of a fix or automated solution to this problem.